# Perform unit test on a Spring controller

Tags: spring, unit-testing

I have the following controller style which I use for displaying result to DataTable.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/list", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    @ResponseBody
    public DataTableObject<PatientBO> list(HttpServletRequest request,
            Locale locale) {
        final DataTableRequestParam param = DataTablesParamUtility
                .getParam(request);
        Map<Integer, String> tableColumn = new HashMap<Integer, String>();
        if (tableColumn.isEmpty()) {
            DataTableUtil.createMap(tableColumn, param.columnProperties);
        }
        return adminPatientManagementService.getList(tableColumn, param,
                locale);
    }
```

and my DataTablesParamUtility

```
public class DataTablesParamUtility {

    public static DataTableRequestParam getParam(HttpServletRequest request)
    {
        if(request.getParameter("sEcho")!=null && request.getParameter("sEcho")!= "")
        {
            DataTableRequestParam param = new DataTableRequestParam();
            param.sEcho = request.getParameter("sEcho");
            param.sSearchKeyword = request.getParameter("sSearch");
            param.bRegexKeyword = Boolean.parseBoolean(request.getParameter("bRegex"));
            param.iDisplayStart = Integer.parseInt( request.getParameter("iDisplayStart") );
            param.iDisplayLength = Integer.parseInt( request.getParameter("iDisplayLength") );
            param.iColumns = Integer.parseInt( request.getParameter("iColumns") );
            param.sSearch = new String[param.iColumns];
            param.bSearchable = new boolean[param.iColumns];
            param.bSortable = new boolean[param.iColumns];
            param.bRegex = new boolean[param.iColumns];
            for(int i=0; i<param.iColumns; i++){
                param.sSearch[i] = request.getParameter("sSearch_"+i);
                param.bSearchable[i] = Boolean.parseBoolean(request.getParameter("bSearchable_"+i));
                param.bSortable[i] = Boolean.parseBoolean(request.getParameter("bSortable_"+i));
                param.bRegex[i] = Boolean.parseBoolean(request.getParameter("bRegex_"+i));
            }

            param.iSortingCols = Integer.parseInt( request.getParameter("iSortingCols") );
            param.sSortDir = new String[param.iSortingCols];
            param.iSortCol = new int[param.iSortingCols];
            for(int i=0; i<param.iSortingCols; i++){
                param.sSortDir[i] = request.getParameter("sSortDir_"+i);
                param.iSortCol[i] = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("iSortCol_"+i));
            }
            param.searchableColumns = request.getParameter("searchableColumns");
            param.columnProperties = request.getParameter("columnProperties");
            param.filterBy = request.getParameter("filterBy");
            param.customSearch  = request.getParameter("customSearch");
            param.startRange  = request.getParameter("startRange");
            param.endRange  = request.getParameter("endRange");
            return param;
        }else
            return null;
    }
}
```

Now I am having problem trying to run a unit test against my controller. This is what I have so far

```
@Test
    public void testGetPatientList() throws Exception {
        PatientBO p1 = new PatientBO();
        p1.setId(1);
        p1.setFirstName("Daenerys Targaryen");
        PatientBO p2 = new PatientBO();
        p2.setId(2);
        p2.setFirstName("John Snow");
        List<PatientBO> patientList = Arrays.asList(p1,p2);
        DataTableObject<PatientBO> dto = new DataTableObject<PatientBO>();
        dto.setAaData(patientList);
        when(patientManagementService.getList(null, null,null)).thenReturn(dto);
         mockMvc.perform(get("/staff/patient/list"))
         .andExpect(status().isOk())
         .andExpect(content().contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE))
         .andExpect(jsonPath("$", hasSize(2)))
         .andExpect(jsonPath("$[0].id", is(1)))
         .andExpect(jsonPath("$[0].firstName", is("Daenerys Targaryen")))
         .andExpect(jsonPath("$[1].id", is(2)))
         .andExpect(jsonPath("$[1].firstName", is("John Snow")));
         verify(patientManagementService, times(1)).getList(null, null,null);
         verifyNoMoreInteractions(patientManagementService);
    }
```

The test fail because there `param` variable is null. My questions are

1. Is my controller design unit testable ?
2. How should my unit test be written ?

Comment: the code you have posted is not enough to be able to answer your question in a detailed way. I never test controllers in pure unit tests as you skip important part of your application (endpoint setup: validation, request types, parameters/body deserialization etc.) untested. Im my opinion you should try to write an integration test. More can be found here: https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/integration-testing.html

Comment: Why oh why... Spring is perfectly capable of binding parameters to objects for you, so no need for your `DataTablesParamUtility` as you should be able to directly bind to `DataTableRequestParam`. Also you aren't writing a unit test you are writing an integration test! Is it testable hardly (or difficult) with all the calls to those static helper methods.

Comment: @M.Deinum. Could you show me how the binding should be done without the `DataTablesParamUtility` ? This is my first attempt on unit testing, so basically not all things can be unit-tested.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can test your endpoint like below if you are using spring SpringBootTest:

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT,
                classes = MyApplication.class)
public class DataTableObjectTest {
    @Autowired
    private TestRestTemplate restTemplate;

    @Test
    public void testDataList() {

        DataTableObject<PatientBO> dto
            = (DataTableObject<PatientBO>) restTemplate.exchange("/list",
                                                                  HttpMethod.GET,
                                                                  request,
                                                                  DataTableObject.class);

        // perform the asserts of dto
    }
}
```

Note : MyApplication class is your spring boot starter class.